# Tool for enumerating assembly information to xml

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

Does anyone know if there is a tool to get all assembly information given an assembly. Prefereably in XML format.

Information needed:

- Full namespaced assembly name
- Title
- Culture
- Configuration
- Version
- Informational version
- Description
- Company
- Product
- Copyright
- Trademark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    public static class AssemblyExtensions
    {
        public static string InfoToXML(this Assembly assembly)
        {
            string name = assembly.FullName;
            string title = String.Empty;
            string description = String.Empty;
            string company = String.Empty;
            string culture = String.Empty;
            string configuration = String.Empty;
            string version = String.Empty;
            string informationalVersion = String.Empty;
            string product = String.Empty;
            string trademark = String.Empty;
            string copyright = String.Empty;

            foreach (var attrib in assembly.GetCustomAttributes(false))
            {
                if (attrib is AssemblyTitleAttribute)
                {
                    title = ((AssemblyTitleAttribute)attrib).Title;
                }

                if (attrib is AssemblyDescriptionAttribute)
                {
                    description = ((AssemblyDescriptionAttribute)attrib).Description;
                }

                if (attrib is AssemblyCompanyAttribute)
                {
                    company = ((AssemblyCompanyAttribute)attrib).Company;
                }

                if (attrib is AssemblyCultureAttribute)
                {
                    culture = ((AssemblyCultureAttribute)attrib).Culture;
                }

                if (attrib is AssemblyConfigurationAttribute)
                {
                    configuration = ((AssemblyConfigurationAttribute)attrib).Configuration;
                }

                if (attrib is AssemblyVersionAttribute)
                {
                    version = ((AssemblyVersionAttribute)attrib).Version;
                }

                if (attrib is AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute)
                {
                    informationalVersion = ((AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute)attrib).InformationalVersion;
                }

                if (attrib is AssemblyProductAttribute)
                {
                    product = ((AssemblyProductAttribute)attrib).Product;
                }

                if (attrib is AssemblyTrademarkAttribute)
                {
                    trademark = ((AssemblyTrademarkAttribute)attrib).Trademark;
                }

                if (attrib is AssemblyCopyrightAttribute)
                {
                    copyright = ((AssemblyCopyrightAttribute)attrib).Copyright;
                }
            }

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(builder);
            XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

            xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("AssemblyInformation");
            xmlWriter.WriteElementString("AssemblyName", name);
            xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Title", title);
            xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Description", description);
            xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Company", company);
            xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Culture", culture);
            xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Configuration", configuration);
            xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Version", version);
            xmlWriter.WriteElementString("InformationalVersion", informationalVersion);
            xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Product", product);
            xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Trademark", trademark);
            xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Copyright", copyright);
            xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

This should get you started. You can add error handling and stuff but this should work.

Comment: Thanks for the effort you did put into this. Really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/). I don't know that it has an XML export but I don't see why you couldn't add it, or write a tool yourself. It's quite easy to iterate over the attributes and extract this kind of information.